# In a really simple react usestate todo list, all checkboxes are working together

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//import Content1 from '../ProfileOnOff/Content1';

const ToDoList = () => {
  const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      value: "Paint the walls and other",
      isChecked: false,
      checkClass: "check_style",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: "Replace toilet stuffs",
      isChecked: false,
      checkClass: "check_style",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      value: "Replace kitchen slabs and sink",
      isChecked: false,
      checkClass: "check_style",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      value: "Floor mobbing",
      isChecked: false,
      checkClass: "check_style",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      value: "Light ang plug points making",
      isChecked: false,
      checkClass: "check_style",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      value: "Place measurement for furniture",
      isChecked: false,
      checkClass: "check_style",
    },
  ]);

  const checkHandler = (event) => {
    let mapped = checkboxValue.map((el, i) => {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        console.log(el.id);
        return {
          ...el,
          isChecked: "checked",
          checkClass: "check_style lined",
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...el,
          isChecked: "",
          checkClass: "check_style ",
        };
      }
    });

    setCheckboxValue(mapped);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h3 className="commonHeading">To Do List </h3>
      <div className="todoCont">
        <ul>
          {checkboxValue.map((todo) => (
            <li key={todo.id}>
              <label className={todo.checkClass}>
                <input
                  defaultChecked={todo.isChecked}
                  onChange={checkHandler}
                  type="checkbox"
                />
                <span></span> {todo.value}
              </label>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ToDoList;
```

this was my code and then just made a list with this array.

When I select one checkbox the label should line through it, but it worked for all the other labels. See in the picture. I just used a class to make that change. but here the class is added for every one in the list.

Comment: Where is the picture ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are a few issues at play here.

First of all you need to isolate the checkbox being acted upon in the handler. This can be done by adding a name prop to each checkbox and then checking for it in the handler `checkBox.id.toString() === event.target.name`.

Secondly the Array.map is overwriting everything incorrectly except the element that was just clicked. Instead you need to only update the one object in the array, that can be done with Array.findIndex(), cloning the array with Array.slice() and then using Array.splice to mutate the cloned array with the new value. This means to keep the code immutable which is important.

Finally we need to invert the checked value, rather than set it to true, this is in order to allow the checkboxes to be unchecked `isChecked: !state[indexToUpdate].isChecked,`.

I've also changed the class to be a derived attribute based on the isChecked value, this avoids data duplication and keeps the code simpler.

See the full solution below.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const ToDoList = () => {
  const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      value: "Paint the walls and other",
      isChecked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: "Replace toilet stuffs",
      isChecked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      value: "Replace kitchen slabs and sink",
      isChecked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      value: "Floor mobbing",
      isChecked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      value: "Light ang plug points making",
      isChecked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      value: "Place measurement for furniture",
      isChecked: false,
    },
  ]);

  const checkHandler = (event) => {
    setCheckboxValue(state => {
      const indexToUpdate = state.findIndex(checkBox => checkBox.id.toString() === event.target.name);
      console.log(indexToUpdate)
      let newState = state.slice()
      newState.splice(indexToUpdate, 1, {
          ...state[indexToUpdate],
          isChecked: !state[indexToUpdate].isChecked,
          checkClass: "check_style lined",
        })
      return newState
    });
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className="commonHeading">To Do List </h3>
      <div className="todoCont">
        <ul>
          {checkboxValue.map((todo) => (
            <li key={todo.id}>
              <label className={`checkbox ${todo.isChecked ? 'lined' : ''}`}>
                <input
                  defaultChecked={todo.isChecked}
                  onChange={checkHandler}
                  type="checkbox"
                  name={todo.id}
                />
                <span></span> {todo.value}
              </label>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<ToDoList />, document.getElementById("react"))
```

```css
.lined {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.checkbox {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just used a class to make that change. but here the class is added for every one in the list.

Lets take a look at the following part of your code:

```js
{ checkboxValue.map((todo) => (
    <li key={todo.id}> 
        <label className={todo.checkClass}>
            <input
                defaultChecked ={todo.isChecked}
                onChange={checkHandler}
                type="checkbox"
            /> 
            <span></span>  {todo.value}
        </label>
    </li>
))}
```

You'll **always** set `className` to `todo.checkClass`.

I think you want to make that condidional, only add the `className` **if** `todo.isChecked`:

```js
<label className={todo.isChecked ? todo.checkClass : ''}>
```

```js
{ checkboxValue.map((todo) => (
    <li key={todo.id}> 
        <label className={todo.isChecked ? todo.checkClass : ''}>
            <input
                defaultChecked={todo.isChecked}
                onChange={checkHandler}
                type="checkbox"
            /> 
            <span></span>  {todo.value}
        </label>
    </li>
))}
```